# Using slice notation yields wrong type hint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I am building a neural network for a project but the type hinting is misleading

Code as follows:

```
import typing
class Layer:
    pass

class Network:
    def __init__(self, *layers: Layer):
        self._layers=layers

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, item: int) -> Layer: #x[0] -> Layer
        pass

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, item: slice) -> list[Layer]: #x[:] -> list
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, item: int | slice) -> Layer | list[Layer]:
       return self._layers[item] #returns tuple, not list - but doesn't flag up as wrong
```

In my test code I have this:

```
x=Network()
layers=x[:] #should be list[Layer]
layers2=x[slice(None,None,None)] #equivalent syntax, should also be list[Layer]
```

What I am seeing instead is this:

The type hint in pycharm for the layers variable is Network

[image]

The type hint in pycharm for the layers2 variable is list

[image]

The pycharm debugger resolves these and correctly determines it's a tuple

[image]

So equivalent syntax (slicing notation using `:`, and by creating a slice object) is yielding two different type hints - one that's correct and one that's wrong.

Comment: Seems to be [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42359).

Comment: @InSync please consider posting an answer - good issue tracker search deserves good visibility, and it'll be easier to update when the linked bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As @InSync says in his comment, this appears to be a bug on pycharm's behalf.

Link to the bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42359

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35136796)